# Firebase snapshot to an array of objects

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Swift and Firebase and I'm building an app but I'm having a very difficult time (and it seems really simple as I'm getting the data printed out...) to convert the data (from Firebase Realtime Database) I retrieve to an array of users...

I would like to be able to do :

```
for user in users {
  print(user.name)
}
```

Output :

```
"Bob"
"John"
...
```

Basically having a simple array with objects inside.

This is how I retrieve my data :

```
let data = Database.database().reference().child("dbusers")
    
    data.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
    }
```

This is the output of the above print statement :

```
Snap (users) {
    0 =     {
        coeff1 = "";
        coeff2 = "";
        id = "";
        userLogo = "";
        userName = "";
        userUrl = " ";
    };
    1 =     {
        coeff1 = 1;
        coeff2 = 1;
        id = 1;
        userLogo = bobbyLogo;
        userName = Bob;
        userUrl = urlOfBobby;
    };
    2 =     {
        coeff1 = 1;
        coeff2 = 1;
        id = 2;
        userLogo = mariaLogo;
        userName = Maria;
        userUrl = urlOfMaria;
    };
    3 =     {
        coeff1 = 1;
        coeff2 = 1;
        id = 3;
        userLogo = johnLogo;
        userName = John;
        userUrl = urlOfJohn;
    };
    4 =     {
        coeff1 = 1;
        coeff2 = 1;
        id = 4;
        userLogo = jamesLogo;
        userName = James;
        userUrl = urlOfJames;
    };
    5 =     {
        coeff1 = 1;
        coeff2 = 1;
        id = 5;
        userLogo = jackLogo;
        userName = Jack;
        userUrl = urlOfJack;
    };
    6 =     {
        coeff1 = 1;
        coeff2 = 1;
        id = 6;
        userLogo = nikolasLogo;
        userName = Nikolas;
        userUrl = urlOfNikolas;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're reading `/dbusers/users`, you get a snapshot that contains all users. You'll need to loop over the child nodes of the `snapshot` to get each individual user, and can then get their `userName` property.

Something like this:

```
let data = Database.database().reference().child("dbusers")    

data.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    for childSnapshot in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        print(childSnapshot.key) // prints the key of each user
        print(childSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath:"userName").value) // prints the userName property
    }
}
```